# How to get group ids by ids of elements of group content?

Tags: 8, group

I use [the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) and I have created several groups and assigned several nodes as content of these groups.

For example, I know id of some node. How can I figure out which groups contain this node ?  That is, how to get group ids by nid, if this node is a content of these groups ? And I don't want to use SQL for it. Are there methods of classes for it ?

Answer (score 5):

The way Group module maintainer [recommended](https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/2769167#comment-11442541):

```
use Drupal\group\Entity\GroupContent;

function getGroupIdsByEntity($entity) {
  $group_ids = [];

  $group_contents = GroupContent::loadByEntity($entity);
  foreach ($group_contents as $group_content) {
    $group_ids[] = $group_content->getGroup()->id();
  }

  return $group_ids;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this: (gids will be your groups ids). I check the entity type because group content will also load the group members.

```
  $ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('group_content')
      ->condition('entity_id', $node->id())
      ->execute();

  $relations = \Drupal\group\Entity\GroupContent::loadMultiple($ids);

  foreach ($relations as $rel) {

    if ($rel->getEntity()->getEntityTypeId() == 'node') {

      $gids[] = $rel->getGroup()->id();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another helpful function in this situation might be `getContentByEntityId($plugin_id, $id);` from `GroupInterface.php`. `$plugin_id` is the content enabler plugin ID to filter on and `$id` is your node id. However, you would need to loop through your groups and do `$groupContentArray = $group->getContentByEntityId($plugin_id, $id)` to get an array of GroupContentEntities (of your node) if they exist for this group.